# in primefaces/ultima: why menu button may die after any page reload

Tags: primefaces

after any page refresh is done, menu button loses its onclick event.
if menu mode is overlay, menu persists invisible.
and if it is static, menu persists as it was first time page loaded.

EDIT:
I suppose that problem is in global settings , since all things nice except this behavior.

EDIT+1:
previous supposition is wrong!  
after debuging my project and ultima demo on browser, I can limit the problem: 
"menu.layout.js `init` function runs before menuButton is rendered"

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jasper de Vries, thanks for your response, what kind of code should I reveal. secondary info: I'm working in large project whose previous layout is omega.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: @Jasper de Vries: thanks, sometimes diving to find the problem is easier than making reproducible example. my friend, I'm working on a large project that has a lot of libraries and global undefault settings!!

Answer (score 0):

... To this concrete problem, I found working solution:

1. in layout.menu.js after `this._super(cfg);` add `var thisThis = this;`
2. replace all occurrences of `this` with `thisThis` after `var thisThis = this;` in `init`
3. put the code after `var thisThis = this;` in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... }`

even if this ignores software engineering code, it's valid :)